# Two related windows not displaying properly

Tags: python, tkinter

Running this code on my linux mint 11 with Python 2.6 would normally lead to creating 2 windows, each of them having a frame with a Button:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

boot = Toplevel()
frame = Frame(root).pack()
button = Button(frame,text="button1").pack()
fr = Frame(boot).pack()
but = Button(fr,text="button2").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But running the code gives me one window (probably the root) with both buttons and another tiny window which has no frame and no button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
fr = Frame(boot).pack()
but=Button(boot, text=...
```

try

```
fr = Frame(boot)
fr.pack()
but=Button(boot, text= ...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer sir, but i still don't understand why i can't pack the frame directly.

Comment: when you say `fr = Frame(boot).pack()`, you are setting fr equal to the return value of the pack() method, which is None.  You want to set fr equal to the frame first and then pack it after.  (It doesn't have to come after the Button line.)

It's similar to when you want to sort a list in python.  If you say `list2 = list1.sort`, list2 is just None, because that's the return value of the sort method.

Comment: I meant `list2 = list1.sort()`